# M220 mouse stops and starts in Ubuntu 20.04.1

Tags: 20.04, mouse, thinkpad, logitech

Using a Logitech/Logicool M220 wireless mouse in Ubuntu 20.04.1 (ThinkPad X1 Carbon 7th gen), the pointer stops randomly and then restarts after a few seconds. Same behavior with a replacement mouse. The receiver is installed in a USB port right next to the mousepad.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is it possible some other hardware is causing this? Any thing plugged into any other USB port? I had this issue with a Bluetooth 3 USB dongle and the Logitech k400 plus till I replaced the Bluetooth dongle with a newer 1.

Comment: Nothing in the other USB port; this isn't a Bluetooth mouse in any case (wifi). This doesn't happen with an older Microsoft wireless mouse.

Comment: Did not ask if it was Bluetooth neither was mine but Bluetooth was INTERFERING with it.

Comment: Sorry, misunderstood. It's not Bluetooth in any case because I never use it on my laptop.